# Pan an Image in ArcGIS StoryMap

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

I have an ArcGIS StoryMap (Cascade variant) that I would like to load an image into that someone can pan around. The image is of an old Sanborn map so zooming in and out would be a good idea. The current service that hosts the image allows me to embed it using a link (see here: http://dc.lib.unc.edu/cdm/ref/collection/ncmaps/id/9084), but it also includes all the other page information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upload the image directly to a Cascade, it will be static. However, if you georeference the image first and place it into a map with no basemap, that would allow you to pan and zoom. My recommendation (assuming you have ArcMap or some other desktop GIS software):

- Open ArcMap
- Georeference the image with just 1 point (it doesn't have to be accurate for this purpose).
- Update the georeferencing
- Close Arcmap
- Select and zip up all the files related to the georeferenced image
- Upload to ArcGIS Online
- Create a new ArcGIS Online map
- Add the georeferenced raster image in
- Toggle off the basemap
- Save
- Add the new map as a page to the story map cascade.

You can now pan and zoom

Comment: ArcGIS Online also supports embedding webpages. It would be a little clunkier.